# colorbox new attribute for class ids

Tags: jquery, colorbox

in colorbox there are two vars ;

```
    // Abstracting the HTML and event identifiers for easy rebranding
    colorbox = 'colorbox',
    prefix = 'cbox',
```

Can I change these via a jquery function when i call colorbox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you cant change the hard coded vars but you can add new ones which is the answer what i was looking for.

Here is what I used to add new class name to cbox. This allows you change the layout of colorbox by assigning a additional class name.

code;

To the **defaults** add cssClass like so;

```
var
// ColorBox Default Settings.   
// See http://colorpowered.com/colorbox for details.
defaults = {
cssClass: "",
```

Find the function **publicMethod.prep**

add this line

```
if(settings.cssClass) $("#cboxOverlay").addClass(settings.cssClass);
```

To add a css class name to your overlay box just add the attribute

```
  $.colorbox({cssClass: 'YourclassName', title: 'Login'..... etc
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you have more than two colorbox in your page, you also should remove the class when the window is closed. Otherwise, the classes will be added.

1. Search for PublicMethod.close function and add:

`if(settings.cssClass) $("#colorbox").removeClass(settings.cssClass);`

Comment: This isn't an answer .. but thanks for the edge case heads up, although you could just set a dummy class for the new colorbox

Answer (score 0):

You can't: it's hardcoded in the sourcecode. You could make a Pull Request on the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox).